# Polynomial division, multivariable, indeterminates

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Trying to understand something in the proof of Nullstellensatz,

> if we have a polynomial $p(x_1,...,x_n,t) \in k[x_1,...,x_n,t]$ with $f(t)$ divides $p(a_1,...,a_n,t)$ for all fixed $(a_1,...,a_n) \in k^n,$ then does $f(t)$ divide $p(x_1,...,x_n,t)$ as a polynomial?

This may not be true for $k$ finite field, but say $k$ is infinite or $k=\mathbb{C}$.

It seems fairly obvious that it must be true, but I do not know how to prove this.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm  not sure, but I would try the following. Look at it first in the ring $k(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)[t]$, which is a Euclidean domain. There you can calculate the remainder of $p(t)$ by $f(t)$ by the usual
$$p(t)=q(t)f(t)+r(t)$$ business, with coefficients in $k(t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n)$ and $\deg r<\deg f$ (as polynomials in $t$). If $r(t)=0$ you are happy. If not, then one of the coefficients of $r$ does not vanish. Then start looking for a vector $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ such that the none of the denominators and one of the numerators of coefficients of $r$ does not vanish. Assume $k$ is infinite.

Comment: (cont'd) Use the fact that over an infinite field no non-zero polynomial vanishes everywhere. Apply that to the product of that numerator and the.denominators.